# How do I remove the system from connected sources section in OMS?

Tags: azure, oms

I have configured the **Microsoft Operations Management Suite** by installing agent on my **windows** systems. It works fine and provides **log analytics**.

I have mistakenly added one of production system as **connected sources**. Now I would like to remove it from the list. Is there is any best practise to remove the agent? Or just un-installing the agent will do the job?

[image]

Comment: Just uninstall the agent.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the better solution.I have just removed work space ID (un-mapped) in Agent. This will be easy and better option because I can come back and add other work space ID.

[image]